# Find $n$ s.t. $Aut(\mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_4 \oplus \mathbb Z_4 \oplus \mathbb Z_6) \cong U(n).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

can we determine the automorphism group of a $U$-group i.e $Aut(U(n))$ ?

I need to find $n$ s.t $Aut(\mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_4 \oplus \mathbb Z_4 \oplus \mathbb Z_6) \cong U(n).$ ? I started by rewriting the external direct product as $U$-group ( unit group $\mod n$ )  , which is $U(560)$ , this is the only idea i got .. am I in the right way ??

Comment: By $U(n)$ do you mean group of units mod $n$, or the unitary group?

Comment: U(n) group of units mod n

Comment: In that case, this is not possible. The automorphism group you are looking at is not abelian, while all $U(n)$ are abelian.

Comment: Why it's nt abelian ?

Comment: Because even $\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$ has non-abelian automorphism group (consider the one that switches the entries and the one that inverts one entry but not the other).

Comment: I'm nt following , I'm taking an abstract algebra 1 course , what reference or chapter can i return to identify when a group isomorphism is abelian or nt ? Thanx in advance !

Comment: Are you sure the Aut part is supposed to be there?

Comment: yes I'm sure , If it's nt then it's solved , U(560)  .

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, it is not possible then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the stated form, the answer is that there is no such $n$, since $U(n)$ is always abelian, while $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_6)$ is not.

To see that the given group of automorphisms is not abelian, we note that it contains the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_4$ as a subgroup (given by those automorphisms that fix the first and last coordinates). And this automorphism group contains the two non-commuting elements $(x,y)\mapsto (y,x)$ and $(x,y)\mapsto (-x,y)$.